# REQUEST_URI negation not working on redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

I am trying to setup my website to redirect to mobile version using .htaccess.
My main intention is to redirect all requests coming from mobile except requests seeking image files directly. Image files are located in three folders under the root folder: /img/ /files/ /userfiles/

I am using the below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipad|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/files/(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/userfiles/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobilesite.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Redirection is taking place for all requests coming from mobile devices without checking the folder conditions.

If I try to access www.normalsite.com/img/somefile.jpg, it is still redirecting me to mobilesite.com even though the condition above should prevent it from doing so.

Can somebody please help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
# Assume this condition works.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipad|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]

# Modified conditions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/files.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)].* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/userfiles.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobilesite.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Add other image extensions here if necessary:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)].* [NC]`

Comment: So you changed RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/files/(.*) [NC] to RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/files.* [NC] - which is not an improvement, is it?